# React Native Sound Loading Error. com.google.android.exoplayer2.b.h$b: AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(44100, 4, 22050)

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a number of sound files in my React Native app that I can play 90% of the time without an issue. However, on occasion instead of playing a sound file I will get the following error:

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.b.h$b: AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(44100, 4, 22050)
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:104:30 in <unknown>
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:414:12 in MessageQueue.__invokeCallback
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:127:11 in <unknown>
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314:8 in MessageQueue.__guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:126:9 in MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
* http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.js:80:58 in <unknown>
```

followed by another error from expo-av since it was unable to load the sound:

```
Cannot complete operation because sound is not loaded.
- node_modules\expo-av\build\Audio\Sound.js:63:18 in Sound._performOperationAndHandleStatusAsync$
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:39 in tryCatch
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

The error is not specific to the file. Sometimes a file will work and then sometimes it will not. Once a file has failed I get errors when trying to load all other files:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Player does not exist.]
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:155:31 in createErrorFromErrorData
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:104:30 in <unknown>
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:414:12 in MessageQueue.__invokeCallback
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:127:11 in <unknown>
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314:8 in MessageQueue.__guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:126:9 in MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
* http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.js:80:58 in <unknown>
```

Refreshing the app also doesn't fix this. I have to close down the expo app and reopen it. I had a quick look in node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules and there appears to be a lot of errors/warnings - is this normal? In addition, I play the sound by using the following:

```
Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(true);
            const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();

            firebase.storage().ref().child(this.props.wave.audio).getDownloadURL()
                .then((url) => {
                    soundObject.loadAsync({ uri: url })
                        .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
                        .then(() => {

                            this.setState({ curRecording: soundObject }); 
                            soundObject.playAsync()
                                .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
                                .then(() => {
                                    this.setState({ actualPlaying: true });
                                    this.props.setSound(soundObject);
                                    //this.updatePlays();
                                    soundObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate((playbackStatus) => {
                                        if (playbackStatus.didJustFinish) {

                                            this.setState({ playing: false, actualPlaying: false });
                                            this.props.changeNum("plays", 1, this.props.wave.key, "wave");
                                            this.props.isNotPlaying();
                                            this.props.next();
                                            this.props.setSound("");

                                            let data = { userid: this.props.ownUserid, wave: this.props.wave.key, type2: "wave" };
                                            firebase.database().ref('/Requests/Plays').push(data).catch(err => { console.log(err) });
                                        }
                                    })
                                });
                        })

                });
```

Does anyone know how to fix this/why this is occuring? I am using expo-av for sound and am testing the app via expo on a physical Pixel 2.

From a noob who is well and truly stuck! All help is welcome!